# Mystery Puzzle Riddle

Tags: riddle, mystery

I don't know how to solve this.

When the clock stops at three, it stirs the anger in me.

See me at:

E-FL
W-SL
S-FP
N-Boundary

P.S: You See, but you do not observe. The distinction is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bohemia, FL - Combining the coordinates with the Sherlock Holmes quote from Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's "A Scandal in Bohemia".

Comment: Maybe expand the explanation a bit, and include the other bits of the clue?

Answer (score 4):

> If 3 o'clock is east and north you get "FL Boundary" which could be the coast of Florida where hurricanes are common, hurricanes which have eyes but can't see.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the spoilers for me

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

> The E, W, S, and N are likely East, West, North, and South. On a combined clock/compass face, at three o'clock, the longer minute hand makes a boundary at 12/North. The hour hand is at 3, and is to the East, at FL. Not sure what the other points mean (pun intended)

obviously I see, but don't yet observe.

Comment: But that's not the answer I am looking for. Nice try though.

Comment: So is the E, S, W, N just a coincidence?

Comment: No, it's part of it too. Let's see what others have to say.

Comment: Alright, will do. Looks like a good puzzle, btw.